# URL not loading in webview but loaded in browser in android?

Tags: javascript, android, url, webview

Some type of Urls are not loading in my app in Webview but it can be loaded in device browser. Following is the example Url which is not working in my code-
"http://apps.takeyourapp.com/testApp/staging/index.html"

```
package com.example.webviewdemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    WebView webViewPlaceholder;
    String URL = "http://apps.takeyourapp.com/testApp/staging/index.html";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webViewPlaceholder = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webholder);
        webViewPlaceholder.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webViewPlaceholder
                .setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webViewPlaceholder.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
        webViewPlaceholder.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webViewPlaceholder.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webViewPlaceholder.loadUrl(URL);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create `WebViewClient` and load `url` like

```
 public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
}
```

And `setWebViewClient` like:

```
    webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://apps.takeyourapp.com/testApp/staging/index.html");
```

And also add `INTERNET` permission into `manifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: don't call view.loadUrl from shouldOverrideUrlLoading. Just return false; otherwise pages like this break your app: http://jsbin.com/gupug/1/quiet

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution.

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebview ;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mWebview  = new WebView(this);

        mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript

        final Activity activity = this;

        mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        mWebview .loadUrl("http://apps.takeyourapp.com/testApp/staging/index.html");
        setContentView(mWebview );

    }

}
```