# Some HTTPS URLs are not loading in Webview

Tags: https, uiwebview, swift2, ios9

I'm upgrading an app to Swift 2 (Xcode 7).

When I'm loading a URL in a Webview a strange problem occurs: some HTTPS URLs won't load. Other URLs (also HTTPS) are working fine.

I already tried setting the NSAppTransportSecurity - NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to YES, but this doesn't fix the problem. Does anybody have any idea what may cause this issue?

Also tried to log via

```
setenv("CFNETWORK_DIAGNOSTICS", "3", 1);
```

but actually I don't know what to search for in the log file in order to track down the cause of this problem.

Comment: Make your class which host the webview conforms to the protocol UIWebViewDelegate and give the implementation for delegate method.func webView(webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: NSError?) {
    }, capture the error code and share which would help more.

Comment: Tried this. Found out that the problem occurs when a 302 redirect is made by a specific domain. What I do not understand is that the redirect seems to work fine in Safari (iPhone) and other browsers, but fails in a webview. Also tried other pages with a 302 redirect, which are also working just fine. Is there a way to show/log the received headers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [URL not loading in webview but loaded in browser in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22113651/url-not-loading-in-webview-but-loaded-in-browser-in-android)